# Определение версии Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, useragent

Суть в том, что userAgent браузера Edge выдаёт следующую строку:
`"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240"`
Как мы можем определить глазами, браузер — Edge v.12. Если мы будем определять парсерами ua, будет тоже самое.
Но на деле-то он не 12:
[image: Описание Microsoft Edge]

Отчего происходит такое несоответствие версии браузера и каким образом в javascript мне определить настоящую версию Edge? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То что вы видите в useragent `Edge/12.10240` - это 12 ревизия **EdgeHTML** ядра отвечающая за рендеринг страницы и 10240 сборка  Windows.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; <64-bit tags>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Safari/<WebKit Rev> Edge/<EdgeHTML Rev>.<Windows Build>
```

То что вы видите в браузере открыв вкладку о приложении - это 20 версия **Microsoft Edge app** отвечающая за интерфейс.

> This version number represents feature updates to the browser application  (i.e. user interface features surrounding the web page itself, such as the address bar, tabs, Cortana, Reading View or Web Notes). As in EdgeHTML, the build version simply represents the current Windows build. The major version numbers between Microsoft Edge and EdgeHTML have diverged and will continue to do so as we deliver updates to the application and underlying platform separately. Unlike the EdgeHTML version number, the Microsoft Edge app version is not incorporated in the UA string, as it does not impact site rendering.

То есть версия **Microsoft Edge app** не влияет на рендеринг сайтов и она не включается в useragent.

Соответствие useragent и версии **Microsoft Edge app** можно поискать тут https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/edge/1

Comment: Господи, как я люблю майкрософт. Спасибо.